# Refresh a table inside a pdialog from other pdialog edit panel JSF, primefaces showcase 6.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog, xhtml

JSF, `Primefaces Showcase 6.0`
Please could you help me? I'm trying to refresh a table which is in a `p:dialog`, from other `p:dialog` from here

```
<p:dialog header="Editar Estado Ficha" widgetVar="dialogo3"
    id="dialogo3" modal="true" height="275" width="400">
    <h:form id="form9">

        <p:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:outputText value="Fecha:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{controllerFichaEstado.fecha}" />
            <h:outputText value="Estado:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{controllerFichaEstado.id_estadoS}" />


            <h:outputText value="Observacion:" />
            <p:inputTextarea value="#{controllerFichaEstado.observacion}"
                cols="10" style="width:100%" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Especifique la observacion" />

            <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" update=":form7:tabla2" 
                icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                actionListener="#{controllerFichaEstado.actionListenerActualizar()}"></p:commandButton>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

to this datatable

```
<p:dialog header="Asignar estado de ficha" widgetVar="fe"
    id="estadoficha" modal="true" height="300" width="75%">
    <h:form id="form7">

        <p:panel header="LISTA DE ESTADO DE FICHA">
            <p:dataTable value="#{controllerFichaEstado.listadoxficha}" var="c"
                id="tabla2">

                <p:column headerText="FICHA">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.ficha.idFicha}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="NOMBRE">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.ficha.estudiante.nombreE}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="APELLIDO">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.ficha.estudiante.apellidoE}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="ESTADO FICHA">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.estado.descripcion}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="FECHA">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.fechaEstado}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="OBSERVACION" style="width:300px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.observacionEstado}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:80px">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" update="form9"
                        onclick="PF('dialogo3').show();"
                        actionListener="#{controllerFichaEstado.actionListenerCargar(c)}"></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":form7:tabla2" 
                        actionListener="#{controllerFichaEstado.actionListenerEliminar(c.idFichaestado,c)}"></p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="Asignar"
        actionListener="#{controllerFichaEstado.limpiar()}"
        onclick="PF('ingresoeficha').show();"></p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

I supposed with this code it going to work but it doesn't 
`update=":form7:tabla2"`, actually it works with a full refresh page (F5), I'd like to work without an all refreshing page

Comment: As first step, please debug whether it's `#{controllerFichaEstado.listadoxficha}` which didn't get updated, or that the ajax response didn't contain the HTML representation of `<p:dataTable>`. Only then an answer can be given.

Comment: #{controllerFichaEstado.listadoxficha} it refresh in a regular p:panelgrid, but when I write this in a p:dialog it does too if i refresh all page (F5), but i dont want to refresh all page again and again, I just want to refresh this table inside a p:dialog without a all page refresh, keeping the pdialog open. Than you in advance for you help